# undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7QWidget14setWindowTitleE7QString'

Tags: c++, qt-creator, uiapplication

I am developing an application with Qt Creator and I'm getting this message

undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7QWidget14setWindowTitleE7QString'

Are there any modules or headers that I should include to remove this error message?

Edit:

The version I'm using is Qt 5.8.0 (MSVC 2015, 32 bit)

The .pro file:

```
QT       += core gui serialport multimedia widgets

TARGET = Prototype
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    patientselect.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    patientselect.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
    patientselect.ui

RESOURCES += \
    resources.qrc
```

Comment: That seems more like a library that isn't being linked to

Comment: @CodyGray that [What is an undefined reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) page has no info on how to do that in Qt Creator

Comment: Actually it's a particular Qt question (rather than a general Q about undefined symbols at linker stage) and it's answered perfectly. I don't think it should be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You need to link with `Qt5Widgets` if you are using Qt5.

The [Qt Widgets module](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-module.html) is not linked by default and has to be specified in your .pro file with:

`QT += widgets`.

Comment: I have the widgets module added in the .pro file but the same error appears.

Comment: @G.land did you have it before or you added that later? If you added later you need to re-run qmake.

Comment: I ran qmake but I am still receiving the same error :(

Comment: @G.land you should post your `.pro` file perhaps to get better suggestions

Answer (score 1):

First, this is not a compiler problem but a linker problem. It happens because some *libraries* are forgotten be to added when building your application. Adding a new   *header* to your include won't help.

Try: check your `.pro` file, does it have something like:

```
QT = core gui
```

Check this [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html#declaring-qt-libraries).

Comment: I did that and ran qmake but nothing happened